# Use string for symfony2 datetime month dropdown

Tags: forms, symfony

I am building a form the standard symfony2 way like so

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
   $builder->add('publishedAt', 'datetime');
}
```

this is working great, but it provides a dropdown for the month like so

```
<select>
   <option value="1">01</option>
   <option value="2">02</option>
   <option value="3">03</option>
</select>
```

What I would really like is a dropdown that uses strings as the option text more like this

```
<select>
    <option value="1">Jan</option>
    <option value="2">Feb</option>
    <option value="3">Mar</option>
</select>
```

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
   $builder->add('publishedAt', 'datetime', array(
        'date_format' => 'yyyy-MMM-dd'
    ));
```

you can play with this date_format to do things like show the year at the end (dd-MMM-yyyy) or show only two digits for the year. (dd-MM-yy). Notice that this date format only accepts the y,M and d formats (so, no day of the week, for example) and that there is no corresponding 'time_format' for the time. More info about the format specifiers [here](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime#TOC-Date-Time-Format-Syntax)

Comment: hrm, I thout I tried that. Works good. However I noticed I can also pass in a 'pattern'. This is not working form me unless if I set it in my fields.html.twig file.